# A Function Cant Be Solved For With SolveSympy

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Sympy module cant seem to solve the following expresion which can be solved if plugged into wolframalpha.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-z+-+sqrt(-rho**2+%2B+36)+solve+for+rho

I have tried changing rationals to true and setting the variables to positive.

```
print (z1)
rf = sy.solve(z1, rho)
```

-z - sqrt(-rho**2 + 36) <-- This is the function to be solved.
[] <--This is the solution an empty set.

The current result is an empty set the expected result is rho = + sqrt(-z^2 +36) or rho = - sqrt(-z^2 +36)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround use `solve(z1, rho, check=False)`, var('z', negative=True) or use `solveset(z1, rho)`. The `solve` is confused by the `sqrt(...) == -z`, perhaps thinking that `sqrt` can never be negative (but if `z < 0` then it's not).

Comment: When you substitute the solutions obtained with `check=False` into the original equation you get two identical values to check: `-z-sqrt(z**2)`. The checker currently has no way to communicate that the solution cannot be zero unless the value of `y` is zero, it just knows that (in general) the solution is not uniformly zero. I think this falls under the category of "trivial solution checking": substitute 0 for any variable and see what solutions you get: when rho is zero z is -6 and when z is 0 rho is +/-6. And SymPy can help you with that step.